# How to escape the double forwardslash in regex (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

How to replace the specific string only using one replace instead of two?

```
 const formattedUrl = url.replace('flashget://', '').replace('&abc','')
```

What I have tried: (Not Working)

```
const formattedUrl = url.replace(/flashget:\/\/ | &abc/g, '').replace('&abc','')
```

**Example**

Input Url: flashget://W0ZMQVNIR0VUXWh0dHA6Ly93d3cuZm9yZWNlLm5ldC93aW43LnJhcltGTEFTSEdFVF0=&abc

Formatted Url: W0ZMQVNIR0VUXWh0dHA6Ly93d3cuZm9yZWNlLm5ldC93aW43LnJhcltGTEFTSEdFVF0=

Comment: Your escape is correct. But you added a space after your double slash that also needs to matched. Remove the spaces around the `|`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the spaces around the `|`

Comment: ops...my bad :D

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt:

https://regex101.com/r/eFO7Eh/2

Search Regex:

```
flashget:\/\/(.*)\&.*$
```

Replace term:

```
$1
```

Just pay attention to the fact that this is a different logic and requires handling capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

remove the space before and after the or `|`. it will work.

```js
let url = "flashget://W0ZMQVNIR0VUXWh0dHA6Ly93d3cuZm9yZWNlLm5ldC93aW43LnJhcltGTEFTSEdFVF0=&abc"
const formattedUrl = url.replace(/flashget:\/\/|&abc/g, '');
console.log(formattedUrl);
```